# Unir dos campos y evitar duplicado de datos en la consulta

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Espero alguien me pueda apoyar, estoy trabajando con una serie de datos, en el campo a.SOLI_FOLIO es único pero en la tabla relacionada, es ID cuenta con 2 Partidas, la cual me la duplica al mostrar los resultado me los duplica, muestro la consulta y los datos que estoy utilizando, es decir unir esos dos campos **Partida = 3390, 3660**, **Monto = 29000.00, 34935.33** y que no me muestre dos veces el Folio del Sistema ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

```
SELECT  b.DEPE_CLAVE AS DEPENDENCIA, a.SOLI_REQUERIDO AS 'FECHA DE RECIBIDO CGCS', a.SOLI_FOLIO AS 'FOLIO DEL SISTEMA',
CONCAT(UPPER(a.SOLI_NOMBRE), ' / ', UPPER(d.SOLICODI_DESCRIPCION)) TEMA, UPPER(c.TIPOCAMP_NOMBRE) AS ASUNTO, a.SOLI_MONTO AS '$ MONTO',
d.SOLICODI_CODIGO AS PARTIDA, d.SOLICODI_MONTO AS 'MONTO POR PARTIDA',CONCAT(e.PROV_NOMBRE, ' ', e.PROV_RAZONSOCIAL, d.SOLICODI_PROV_NOMBRE ,' ', d.SOLICODI_PROV_RAZON) AS PROVEEDOR, 
UPPER(f.ESTA_NOMBRE) AS ESTATUS, a.SOLI_ASIGNADO_A, u.USUA_NOMBRE

FROM TBL_SOLICITUD as a

    INNER JOIN CAT_DEPENDENCIA        as b ON b.DEPE_ID     = a.DEPE_ID
    INNER JOIN CAT_TIPOCAMPANA        as c ON c.TIPOCAMP_ID = a.TIPOCAMP_ID
    LEFT JOIN TBL_SOLICITUD_CODIGO    as d ON d.SOLI_ID = a.SOLI_ID
    LEFT JOIN VW_CAT_PROVEEDOR_SELECT as e ON e.PROV_ID = d.SOLICODI_PROV_ID
    INNER JOIN CAT_ESTATUS            as f ON f.ESTA_ID = a.ESTA_ID
    LEFT JOIN SIS_USUARIO as u ON a.SOLI_ASIGNADO_A = u.USUA_ID

WHERE (c.TIPOCAMP_ID = 3) AND  F.ESTA_NOMBRE NOT IN('ELIMINADO')  AND  A.SOLI_ID NOT IN(1075) 
ORDER BY a.SOLI_FOLIO
```

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes usar un distinct, aqui te dejo la documentacion https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: @LuisGarcia, mas bien quiero unir esos dos campos es decir Partida 3390, 3660, y que no me muestre dos veces el Folio del Sistema, corrijo la pregunta.

Comment: Para el motor de base de datos son dos filas distintas porque tienen datos distintos (incluso si usa ditinct). No espere que el motor "combine" filas como una hoja de calculo en la que se pueden combinar celdas. Si lo que quiere lograr es que se presenten como celdas combinadas; debe implementarlo en la capa de presentacion de su aplicacion (el source-code que toma el resultado de la base de datos y lo renderiza). Si lo que quiere es que no se duplique en la consulta debe usar distinct (sin las columnas que diferencian las filas) o usar funciones de agrupamiento en las columnas que difieren

Comment: @MauricioOrtega Como puedo hacer eso de agrupamiento en las columnas?.. aun no se mucho de SQL, disculpa.

Answer (score 0):

Para esto en lugar de hacer un join, que va a repetir los registros, deberías hacer un subquery, y para concatenar los campos de distintos registros el truco está en leerlo como XML.
Acá te dejo un ejemplo de cómo mostrar las partidas separadas por coma.

```
SELECT 
    a.SOLI_FOLIO AS 'FOLIO DEL SISTEMA',
    SELECT SUBSTRING( 
    ( 
        SELECT ',' + d.SOLICODI_CODIGO AS 'data()'
        FROM TBL_SOLICITUD_CODIGO AS d
        WHERE d.SOLI_ID = a.SOLI_ID
        FOR XML PATH('') 
    ), 2 , 9999) As PARTIDA
FROM TBL_SOLICITUD AS a
```

Suerte!